# Entity framework not saving new item

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have odd problem.  The code below wont save new `LookupGroup` objects

```
LookupGroup lookup = null;

using (var db = new WaybackDbContext())
{
    lookup = db.LookupGroups.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(lookupName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

    if (lookup == null)
    {
        lookup = new LookupGroup
        {
            Name = lookupName
        };
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

The `LookupGroup` is initiated but it isn't saved and its id is 0.

What could be stopping it from saving?

Comment: `db.LookupGroups.Add(lookup);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add it to context:

```
if (lookup == null)
{
    lookup = new LookupGroup
    {
        Name = lookupName
    };
    db.LookupGroups.Add(lookup);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```